# Java Method Complexity - Troubling Figuring it Out

Tags: for-loop, big-o, time-complexity

I was doing a computer science practice test for UIL when I encountered this segment of code (there were more methods in the `Structure<E>` class, but they didn't seem relevant to the problem):

```
public class Structure<E> 
{
    private E data;
    private Structure<E> s;

    Structure(E d) 
    {
        data = d; 
    }

    public void add(E d)
    {
        if (s == null)
            s = new Structure<E>(d);
        else
            s.add(d);
    }
}

// Client method
public Structure<Integer> demo(int[] vals)
{
    Structure<Integer> s;
    s = new Structure<Integer>(vals[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
        s.add(vals[i]);
    return s;
}
```

So the question asked me to determine the most-restrictive complexity of the `demo()` client method. I read up on big O notation (before taking the test of course!) and it said that single loop operations, such as adding elements into a list one by one, should have linear complexity, or **O(N)**.

However, the correct answer actually turned out to be **O(N^2)**. I'm confused as to why this is, could somebody please explain it to me? Because I thought that **O(N^2)** complexity was common in *nested* `for` loops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is O(n^2) because the recursive function `add` has an implicit traversal, i.e., a second loop in it, something like this:

```
s = new Structure<Integer>(vals[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        Structure<Integer> p = s;
        while (p.s != null) p = p.s;
        p.s = new Structure<E>(d);
 }
```

Comment: Okay, so it basically loops to the end of the linked list and tacks the new element to the end? And that traversing happens within the outer loop, making it O(N^2)?